# Flash at the first launch of my function fade in fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make a transition fade in fade out on two images the first pass makes a flash not very pretty, after that works normally. 
I used jquery for the JS part, I tried to fix the problem by replacing fade in fade out by `stop (). FadeTo ()` without any result. It looks like the image comes in suddenly without transition.
Have you ever encountered this problem?
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="slider">
      <img src="img1" class="img activeimg" alt="" />
      <img src="img2" class="img" alt="" />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.activeimg{
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
   var app = {
  init: function() {

   app.start();

},

start: function(){

    setInterval(app.nextimg, 10000);

},

nextimg: function(){

    var $imgactive = $('.activeimg');
    var $imgnext = $imgactive.next();

    if ($imgnext.length === 0){
      $imgnext = $('.img').first();
    }

    app.afficheimage($imgnext);

  },


afficheimage: function($image){


    $('.activeimg').fadeOut(2500).removeClass('activeimg');

    $image.fadeIn(2500).addClass('activeimg');

}

};
$(app.init);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should start by editing your code. Your HTML is invalid and your JavaScript begins with `},`. Please post a minimal version of your code that is intact by itself.

Comment: @spiral-dev is this what you re trying to accomplish? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WgWGVv

Comment: yes that's exactly it, I congratulate you and thank you for your help.
Thanks again.